# when a method returns an instance variable, do i use a deep copy or a shallow copy to copy the variable?

Tags: python, class, copy, instance-variables, deep-copy

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy. Working on an assignment and when a method returns an instance variable, we're meant to return a copy of it to prevent aliasing, but this concept wasn't really reviewed in class and the professors are honestly unhelpful, so I'm utterly lost.

Comment: @Arcanus yes! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

who explains better than python itself :

> **The difference between shallow and deep copying** is only relevant for
> compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or
> class instances):
>
> **A shallow copy** constructs a new compound object and then (to the
> extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
> the original.
>
> **A deep copy** constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
> inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.
>
> Two problems often exist with deep copy operations that don’t exist
> with shallow copy operations:
>
> Recursive objects (compound objects that, directly or indirectly,
> contain a reference to themselves) may cause a recursive loop.
>
> Because deep copy copies everything it may copy too much, such as data
> which is intended to be shared between copies.
>
> The deepcopy() function avoids these problems by:
>
> keeping a memo dictionary of objects already copied during the current
> copying pass; and
>
> letting user-defined classes override the copying operation or the set
> of components copied.

*Source : [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)*

---

Simple explanation is deep copies will change when the original variable changes because they use the same memory location, but shallow copies are like separate from the original variable.

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

DeepList = myList # Deep Copy (uses the same memory location)
myList[0] = 5

print(DeepList) # [5, 2, 3, 4, 5]


anotherList = [1,2,3,4,5]
ShallowList = anotherList[:]

anotherList[0] = 5

print(anotherList) # [5, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(ShallowList) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

you can convert a list from Deep-Copy to Shallow-Copy using `[:]` and for dicts you can use `.copy()`

**example :**

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
myDict = {'firstname':'Abolfazl','lastname':'ghaemi'}

myShallowListCopy = myList[:]
myShallowDictCopy = myDict.copy()
```

> **Shallow Copies are much faster than deep copies**